# Appdelegate launch options nil from notification action

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to perform some logic on the notification user information that the application receives when it launches for the first time, the issue I'm having is that when the user taps the notification normally without using any of the notification actions the launch options isn't nil and so I can do what I need to do.

But whenever I tap a notification action to open up the application for the first time, the notifications userInfo is nil so I can't do anything.

This is current logic I'm using to retrieve the notification userInfo from the launch options.

```
if (launchOptions) {

   // Get the notificaion from launch options
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
}
```

And I'm also registering my actions the normal way but I can't seem to get my head around why the launch options would be nil if you select a action compared to selecting a normal notification.

Comment: Are you using Remote notification (triggered by server) or some local scheduled on device based on time locally ?

Comment: Remote notification

Comment: And which method from AppDelegate did you implement it on ? Also are you doing iOS 10 and higher only or you want to support iOS 9 as well - as there were some big changes around notification in between of those versions

Comment: Make sure you are removing the application from background and launching it again by clicking on notification.